# Getting issue while downloading file from blob storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

Hi i have to download a 5 to 6 GB file from blob storage, on downloading  i am getting the below mentioned error each time.

```
Error-:
```

Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

```
My code for downloading:

protected void btn_download_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

 AccountFileTransfer = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=" + ACCOUNTNAME + ";AccountKey=" + ACCOUNTKEY);

 if (AccountFileTransfer != null)
    {
        BlobClientFileTransfer = AccountFileTransfer.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        ContainerFileTransfer = BlobClientFileTransfer.GetContainerReference(CONTAINER);
        ContainerFileTransfer.CreateIfNotExist();
        BlobRequestOptions options = new BlobRequestOptions();
        options.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 180, 0);
    }

  var blob = ContainerFileTransfer.GetBlockBlobReference(downloadfile);

    var sasUrl = blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri;


    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = new CloudBlockBlob(sasUrl);

   //blobSize = Convert.ToInt32(lblfilesize.Text.ToString());
    blockSize = 5 * 1024*1024;
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM";
    System.String disHeader = "Attachment; Filename=\"" + blockBlob.Name + "\"";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", disHeader);
    for ( offset = 0; offset < blobSize; offset += blockSize)
    {
        using (var blobStream = blockBlob.OpenRead())
        {
            if ((offset + blockSize) > blobSize)
            {
                blockSize =(blobSize - offset);
            }

            byte[] buffer = new byte[blockSize];
            blobStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
            Response.Flush();
        }
    }
    Response.End();
```

}

Comment: Have you tried reducing the block size from 5 MB to say 1 MB (or may be even lower)?

Comment: .I have to download .iso file and there is no issue on downloading a file size in mb but when  i download a file (size 3 GB) after making a blob size 4 mb as suggested by you the iso file get downloaded but each file size  is 0 KB.